# C++ Conversion To C#

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0, visual-c++, casting

I've got the following situation:

```
struct object1  {

    bool a:1;
    bool b:1;
    uint8_t c:2;
    bool d:1;
    abc  e:3;

    uint16_t header;
    uint8_t footer;
    uint8_t mid[4];
}
```

I may not know the syntax but in C# playing with bits isn't as easy as C++. I've used the BitArray and BitConverter Classes to make methods to populate the data but I've run into the problem:

```
object1 * rqr = (object1  *) &Msg.Data[2];
```

Basically they are casting the object to an array of bytes. Every search I've done screams serialization but to truly convert the above line I can't have any extra metadata or anything.

I really do want to create a pointer to a memory location and "cast" that location to said object. Is this possible? If not, is there a solution to this issue? I can't imagine that bit manipulation on this level has been left out completely. I'd default to me just not knowing before assuming that.

Edit::
I understand that C# does not allow for pointers onto manage types. What I'm asking is if there was a way to say:

```
Byte[] ayData = new Byte[8];
ObjectOfSize8 nObject =  (ObjectOfSize8)ayData;
```

I understand the above will not work, but, is there something in the language that will allow data casting if you're smart enough to understand the memory sizes of the objects?

Comment: Depending on what `&Msg.Data[2]` returns, that line may violate the strict aliasing rule.  Only `char*` is a special case.  Also, C# does not allow for pointers to managed types.  Why not just use an array of bytes and create a class to handle creating and extracting messages?

Comment: I'm trying to hold strict to the conversion of the code; Ironically the "Data" (Data[2]) structure is a large Byte array, so char* is actually what's returned. The data is being passed back and forth. The purpose to this question is twofold. The data is being manipulated via many structures that are being cast upon the data. Programming up functions to handle the manipulation of the data is taking me a while, so I was wondering if there was a method to apply casting upon an array of data. The second is simply to see if there was a way to "call" arbitrary data an object.

Comment: why are you trying to do this in C#? it's really not meant for this sort of thing. You'd be better off doing it in C++ and then transferring to a not bitfielded structure and then returning that to C#.

Comment: No, you cannot overlay a struct or any object onto a byte array in C#.  Just parse the buffer, it's not difficult.

Comment: @BlndLeadingDef: Because often times people come here with 90% of a "solution" and ask us to solve that last 10%.  Almost as often, that last 10% makes no sense, so we need to know what you are actually trying to accomplish to provide a better alternative that you may not have considered.  (credit to R. Chen on the whole "last 10% makes no sense" thing. It happens so often he wrote a blog entry about it).  It doesn't really matter what you *want* to do; you can't solve your problem this way in C#.

Comment: Ed S. Thank you for your replies; I didn't convey that earlier. It's not about difficulty. It's time consumption. There's about 30 different structures that can be applied to the same memory buffer. In the application I'm working with it's used through-out. I wasn't sure if there was any way to do that.

Comment: Have you tried using bitwise operations? All you need is some shifting and bitwise and and or.

Comment: Well, you may take Mgetz up on his suggestion then; do the parsing in C++ and return the result to C# land.  Heck, you could even write a CLI wrapper so that you can use these objects as if they were C# types (because, well, they will be CLR types at that point.)

Comment: @David Heffernan: Hmm? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @EdS. Yes, that may be the way I have to do it. I'll be the first to admit I don't know all of the quirks of the language so that's why I come here to ask. To you experts.

Comment: You can do it easily in C#. For example. To read the second least significant bit (i.e. bit 1) from a byte b you do: (b >> 1) && 1. Or to read bits 1 and 2 you do (b >>) && 3. Use << and || to set bits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah, you're speaking about converting an object to fit the container in the structure. Yes, I agree that's easy and it's possible using the method specified, but what I'm speaking about is the definition of an object based on the size of the object. You can redefine the object by casting it to another equally sized object. This makes defining and manipulating the underlying data easy. Thanks for your post.

Comment: @Mgetz I understand my comment may have been hostile in nature, I have removed the comment, and would like to apologize as it was not meant that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you ask with type casting in C#. I suspect the cleanest way to do what you need may be to pin the C# struct. Then you've got an IntPtr that you can use with Marshal.Copy to copy to and from a byte array.

As for the bitfields, they'll need to be managed using bitwise shift, bitwise OR and bitwise AND operations.

Comment: Thanks for the message, I'd like to mark Ed S. answer as being correct only as he was initially the one who mentioned it. If he does not post an answer I will mark yours as such within the hour.

Comment: Ed S. didn't suggest pinning and copying, FWIW. His suggestions were different.

Comment: And I'm not posting an answer either way :).  Accept this one.

Comment: As requested; Thanks for your help guys. I appreciate your replies and support.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your bitfield problem with a struct that handles the bit shifting and masking for you:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=1)]
public struct BitField8
{
    private byte _bits;

    private static readonly byte[] Masks = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff };
    public BitField8(int val)
    {
        _bits = (byte) val;
    }

    public byte Get(int bit, int length = 1)
    {
        int shift = bit + length - 1;
        return (byte) ((_bits >> shift) & Masks[length-1]);
    }

    public void Set(int bit, int length, int val)
    {
        int mask = Masks[length-1];
        int shift = bit + length - 1;
        val = (val & mask) << shift;
        mask = ~(mask << shift);
        _bits = (byte)((_bits & mask) | val);
    }
}
```

So in your example:

```
bool a:1;
bool b:1;
uint8_t c:2;
bool d:1;
abc  e:3;
```

You would set `a` by calling `Set(0, 1, 1)` (set a to 1).

To give `c` the value of 3, you would call `Set(3, 2, 3)`. (`c` occupies bits 2 and 3).

That basically duplicates the functionality of C++ bitfields, although I'll admit that I might have the bit order wrong. I don't really know if the C++ compiler put `a` at bit 0 or at bit 7.

You can do something similar with 16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit bitfields.

So your struct would contain:

```
BitField8 myBitfield;
```

Comment: Jim thanks for the answer. I really appreciate the time you took to provide such a detailed response. I was looking to see if there was an equivalent syntax or method in C# to deal with the multitude of casting. David's idea of pinning is interesting. This does answer how to handle the situation of bit-field manipulation in a clean and concise way though.